# Div height not same for different divs

Tags: html, css

I wrote a responsive site where I've multiple `divs` with same height and width. Here is the screenshot:
[image: img]
There are 4 divs which are of same height and width. However 3rd div isn't proper. Its height isn't same as other 3 `divs`. How can I make height of 3rd `div` same as other divs?
Here is the code:

**`CSS and HTML Code:`**

```css
.category1{
  width: 100%;
  height : 40%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0067ac; 
}
.category2{
  width: 100%;
  height : 40%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey; 
}
/*#category1{
font-size: 14px;
}*/
.ctgryName1{
  color: #0067ac;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "robotRegular";
}
.ctgryName2{
  color: grey;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "robotRegular";
}
.ctgryIcon1{
  background-image: url("../JunosImages/mob/timed-active_icon.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: block;           
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: 0.7%;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "category1">
  <span class = "ctgryName1">JNCIA - Junos</span>
</div>
<div class = "category1" id="catergory1">
  <span class = "ctgryName1">Timed Test</span>
</div>
<div class = "category2">
  <span class = "ctgryName2">Timed Tests with items from all topics</span>
  <span class = "ctgryIcon1 pull-right"></span>
</div>
<div class = "category1">
  <span class = "ctgryName1">Practice Test Topics</span>
</div>
```

Comment: To save yourself from frustration, use boostrap. You can override bootstrap styles if you want, write once, run everywhere

Comment: I'm supposed to use `media queries`, that is the problem. That is client requirement.

Comment: It's due to the font-size (18 vs 24). You could try adding some padding between the text to get the same height. I don't think setting the height to 40% is doing anything in this case.

Comment: @frosty: Padding? Yeah, let me try it. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @Dummy: Client requirements tell that I should use media queries and be less `reliant` on bootstrap.

Comment: @frosty: I tried `padding-bottom: 3px`, the size didn't increase.

Comment: Did you add that to `.category2`? You'd want top and bottom padding as well.

Comment: @frosty: yeah, I added both top and bottom padding to `.category2`. It didn'twork.

Comment: I have noticed that when you use percent for CHILD elements' height property, it wont do anything since child element like in your case will just take up its allotted height space, but if you choose other unit say `em`, it does increase the height of child elements, however, if child element is a container, it works, put a border around your elements and see the effect, I had the same problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried line-height property? Try my solution :)

```css
.category1{
        width: 100%;
        line-height : 40px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #0067ac;   
    }
    .category2{
        width: 100%;
        line-height : 40px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;  
    }
    #category1{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .ctgryName1{
        color: #0067ac;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-family: "robotRegular";
    }
    .ctgryName2{
        color: grey;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-family: "robotRegular";
    }
    .ctgryIcon1{
        background-image: url("../JunosImages/mob/timed-active_icon.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        display: block;
        width: 12px;
    }
```

```html
<div class = "category1">
                        <span class = "ctgryName1">JNCIA - Junos</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "category1" id="catergory1">
                        <span class = "ctgryName1">Timed Test</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "category2">
                        <span class = "ctgryName2">Timed Tests with items from all topics</span>
                        <span class = "ctgryIcon1 pull-right"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "category1">
                        <span class = "ctgryName1">Practice Test Topics</span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Excellent.... Thank you :) Does line height work for `landscape` mode? Above `css` is for `portrait` mode.

Comment: It works too. Also, you can set vertical-align instead padding-top or padding-bottom property

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to same height and width for all div Please Try my solution as below.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {   
    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".cat1").map(function () {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get());
            
    $(".cat1").css("height",maxHeight);
});
```

```css
.category1{
    width: 100%;
    line-height : 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0067ac;   
}
.cat1 { min-height:50px;}
.category2{
    width: 100%;
    line-height : 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;  
}
#category1{
    font-size: 14px;
}
.ctgryName1{
    color: #0067ac;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: "robotRegular";
}
.ctgryName2{
    color: grey;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: "robotRegular";
}
.ctgryIcon1{
    background-image: url("../JunosImages/mob/timed-active_icon.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "category1 cat1">
    <span class = "ctgryName1">JNCIA - Junos</span>
</div>
<div class = "category1 cat1" id="catergory1">
    <span class = "ctgryName1">Timed Test</span>
</div>
<div class = "category2 cat1">
    <span class = "ctgryName2"> Timed Tests with items from all topicsTimed Tests with items from all topicsTimed Tests with items from all topics Timed Tests with items from all topics Timed Tests with items from all topicsTimed Tests with items from all topicsTimed Tests with items from all topics Timed Tests with items from all topics</span>
    <span class = "ctgryIcon1 pull-right"></span>
</div>
<div class = "category1 cat1">
    <span class = "ctgryName1">Practice Test Topics</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried your code? It won't return exact results.

Comment: It will rreturn same height foe all div either div  have content  or not .  or    line height dose not work if you have  more content  in one div & less content in other div.      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725035/div-height-not-same-for-different-divs/30725817?noredirect=1#comment49508908_30725817